# emacs: Fold if else blocks when editing .html.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, code-folding

I'm editing a piece of code like this:

```
<% if foo %>
    <p>No attractions at this park.</p>
<% else %>
    Many
    Many lines in this block
<% end %>
```

When my emacs point is inside the `<% else %>`, is it possible to fold that block? I usually do this kind of thing with C-c C-f, which I believe is from web-mode.el. But it doesn't work for me in this case.

Comment: emacs comes with a built in code folding mode, `hs-minor-mode`. Checkout  [`fold-dwim`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/fold-dwim) package. it might work, but i' m not too sure. Give it a shot

Comment: could you post a feature request on github please

Comment: I think [yafolding](https://github.com/zenozeng/yafolding.el) will work, it's based on indentation.